# Definition of $x^\alpha$

Tags: exponentiation

I've formally defined the power whose base is a positive number and its exponent is a real non-zero number like this:

$$x^{\alpha}=\sup\left\{x^p\in\mathbb{R}\mid p\in\mathbb{Q},0<p\leq\alpha\right\},\text{ if $\alpha>0$.}$$
$$x^{\alpha}=\inf\left\{x^p\in\mathbb{R}\mid p\in\mathbb{Q},\alpha\leq p<0\right\},\text{ if $\alpha<0$.}$$

I want to prove the properties which are true for rational numbers ($x>0,\alpha,\beta\neq 0$):

1. $x^\alpha\cdot x^\beta=x^{\alpha+\beta}$.
2. $(x^\alpha)^\beta=x^{\alpha\cdot\beta}$.
3. $(x\cdot y)^\alpha=x^\alpha\cdot y^\alpha$.

Any ideas? My problem is that there're 2 supremum and I don't have any idea to handle that. I hope, I didn't commit any mistake (sorry for my English!).

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: If $A,B$ are nonempty sets of nonnegative real numbers then $(\sup A)(\sup B) = \sup (AB)$ where $AB = \{ ab \mid a\in A,\ b\in B \}$.

Comment: I haven't do anything. I know that property and that I must apply in the first property when $\alpha,\beta>0$. But with the rest is different. I got stuck at the beginning. For example, for the second it would be (\alpha,\beta>0):

$$(x^\alpha)^\beta=\sup\left\{(x^\alpha)^p\middle|0<p\leq \beta\right\}=$$
$$\sup\left\{(\sup\left\{x^p\middle|0<p\leq\alpha\right\})^q\middle|0<q\leq \beta\right\}.$$

And now, what? How can I go from that to:

$$\left\{x^p\middle|0<p\leq\alpha\cdot\beta\right\}.$$

Comment: BTW, your English is good. Tú inglés es bueno.

Comment: For nested suprema:
$$\sup \{ \sup \{ f(x,y) \mid x\in X \} \mid y\in Y \} = \sup \{ f(x,y) \mid x\in X,\ y\in Y \}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are nonempty sets of nonnegative real numbers then $(\sup A)(\sup B) = \sup (AB)$ and $(\inf A)(\inf B)=\inf (AB),$ where $AB = \{ ab \mid a\in A,\ b\in B \}$.

So for example, if $\alpha,\beta>0,$ then
$$\begin{align}
x^\alpha \cdot x^\beta
&= \sup\{x^q \mid q\in\mathbb{Q},\ 0<q\leq\alpha\} \cdot \sup\{x^r \mid r\in\mathbb{Q},\ 0<r\leq\beta\}
\\
&= \sup\{x^q\cdot x^r \mid q,r\in\mathbb{Q},\ 0<q\leq\alpha,\ 0<r\leq\beta\})
\\
&= \sup\{x^{q+r} \mid q,r\in\mathbb{Q},\ 0<q+r\leq\alpha+\beta\})
\\
&= \sup\{x^{s} \mid s\in\mathbb{Q},\ 0<s\leq\alpha+\beta\})
\\
&= x^{\alpha+\beta}
.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both negatives, it is obvious too. My problem is when $\alpha\cdot\beta<0$. Maybe if, for example, $\beta<0<\alpha$, I should prove that:

$$x^\alpha=\inf\left\{x^p\middle|\alpha\leq p\right\}.$$

Comment: I think the hard property would be the second one. I don't know what to do with two supremum. By the way, thank you very much.

Comment: @RaúlFiligranaVillalba. You mean when you have nested suprema like $\sup \{ \sup \{ (x^q)^r \mid q\in Q \} \mid r\in R \}$ (for some sets $Q,R$)? Then you can just write them as one supremum: $\sup \{ (x^q)^r \mid q\in Q,\ r\in R \}$.

Comment: And why can you do that?

Comment: @RaúlFiligranaVillalba. Do you accept $\max(a_1,\ldots,a_m, b_1,\ldots, b_n) = \max(\max(a1_1,\ldots,a_m), \max(b_1,\ldots,b_n))$? If so, can you also accept that $\sup(\sup(A), \sup(B), \sup(C)) = \sup(A \cup B \cup C)$?